# Common roots in a quadratic and a cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, cubics

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x+b$ and $g(x)=x^2+bx-3$ where $b$ is a real number.  What is the sum of all possible values of $b$ for which the equations $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$ have a common root?
I just need a hint like from where should I start?

Comment: The set of equation is invariant under substitution $(x,b) \to (-x,-b)$. So if $r$ is a common root for given $b$, can you find a common root when $b$ is replaced by $-b$? What does it implies for the possible values of $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Any common root is a root of $xg(x)-f(x)$.

Comment: Nice twist to get rid of the cubic!

Comment: Because of the special shapes, it gets rid of more. Symmetry is nice.

Comment: Thnx I got the answer only value of b=0 , but what do you mean by " because of special shapes ,it gets rid of more"

Comment: And is multiplying by x right here (( even though it gives the right answer))!!

Comment: The fact I wrote down is obviously true. Now about your $b=0$. Tou presumably got $b(x^2-1)=0$. If $b\ne 0$, that leaves the possibility $x=\pm 1$. Did you trace out the consequences of that?

Comment: Also when we multiplied g(x)×x  didn't we make another root of g(x) that is 0 ; so why doesn't that make any difference ; and can I always mutiply by x in one equation in such questions and when I can't??

Comment: Yes if x=+-1 then these should be the roots of g(x) and f(x) but for these the equations are giving two contradictory values of b for x=+-1.

Comment: The logic goes like this: **If** there is a common root, it is a root of $xg(x)-f(x)=0$. Now trace out what that possibilities that gives. It could be in general that some of the roots of $xg(x)-f(x)$ are not common roots of our two original polynomials? Did you check $x=\pm 1$ and the $b=2$ and $b=-2$ that they yield?  From the comment, I suspect you may not have.

Comment: They give two different possibilities for $b$. Do these work, have you checked? After all, there may be more than one value of $b$ for which there is a common root. And in fact there are. If you keep having difficulty, I can flesh out the hint into a complete analysis. It is quite short.

Comment: You wanted a hint only, but I want to make sure you got the right answer. The values of $b$ that work are $0$, $2$, and $-2$.  Note that if we just want the sum (and that's all the problem asks for) then the invariance argument of achille hui is much nicer, since it sidesteps finding the possible values of $b$, given there are only finitely many.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the common root

$$0=y^3-3y+b=y(y^2+by-3)-b(y^2+by-3)=3b-b^2y$$

Either $b=0,$ or $y=\dfrac3b$

Put this value of $y$ in $y^2+by-3=0$

Comment: I must be missing something with the algebra here.  Where did the $3b-b^2y$ come from?

Comment: @abiessu, $$\dfrac{y^3-3y+b}{y^2+by-3}=y-b+\dfrac{3b-b^2y}{y^2+by-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $f(x),g(x)$ have a common root, then there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=?$

Extending this, the $?$ becomes $0$.  As demonstrated in other answers, a root $x=0$ can be added to make the two functions have the same degree, with $xg(x)-f(x)=0$, and then the problem becomes quadratic at worst.

Comment: Sorry,but I don't quite understand the meaning of these symbols can you please put the hint in words.

Comment: I have put in some more words.

Comment: Thnx,already got the answer but I still don't understand what you meant by "the problem becomes quadratic at worst" is the quadratic equation which we got is bad, I thought it was good :-)  as it was this quadratic equation which gave me the answer.

Comment: No, by "quadratic at worst" I mean that it is no longer cubic, or any higher power.  A quadratic is easily solvable using basic algebra.  Any higher power is not usually so easily solved.